# Wkhtmltopdf unable to use the relative path for save() in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I am using PDF Snappy to generate PDF files from views in Laravel 4.

I can use this code using download() without any problem and the file is generated and I can save it:

```
$pdf = PDFSnappy::loadView($pdfView, $dataForPDF);
return $pdf->download( 'invoice.pdf' );
```

However, when I try to use the save() with this code:

```
$pathToFile = "invoices/2015/full/invoice.pdf";

$pdf = PDFSnappy::loadView($pdfView, $dataForPDF);
return $pdf->save( $pathToFile );
```

I get this error message:

```
Object of class Barryvdh\\Snappy\\PdfWrapper could not be converted to string
```

If I try something like this:

```
$pathToFile = url() . '/' . "invoices/2015/full/invoice.pdf";

$pdf = PDFSnappy::loadView($pdfView, $dataForPDF);
return $pdf->save( $pathToFile );
```

I get this error message:

```
The output file's directory http://laravel.dev/invoices/2015/full/ could not be created.
```

I am on Windows using WAMP, could that be a problem?

How can I save a file to my `/public` folder in Laravel inside `invoices/2015/full/` ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it seems that the solution is to remove `return` from this:

`return $pdf->save( $pathToFile );`

and use this code instead:

`$pdf->save( $pathToFile );`

And no additional url tweaking is necessary, you can use the relative "public" paths where you want to save your pdfs.

Hope it helps somebody in the future ;)